# Minimum UI5 version required for "timeseries_line" VIZFrame

Tags: javascript, sapui5

On my local develop machine i have installed SAPUI5 version 1.40.
On my SAP Server UI5 version 1.28 is installed.

I try to display a VIZFrame with type:"timeseries_line". On the local machine everything works fine. On the server i get an "valueaxis is null" Error.

Is there anyone who get this working with version 1.28 and earlier?

Comment: Even if it would be possible to get this running you should rather spend the effort to upgrade. Versions lower than 1.32 should not be used anymore: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/versionoverview.html

Comment: I solved my problem with a little workaround.

http://edelui.blogspot.de/2017/03/sapui5-altere-version-laden-eclipse.html

Comment: Nice. Maybe you frame your question less restrictive next time? You asked for a workaround for version 1.28, now you load the newest version from another source. Two different things.

Comment: Sorry. Maybe I was too imprecise